# Using functions inside scripts required by NodeJS's required()

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, require

How do you access a function that is inside one of the scripts that you have "included" using Node's require() function?

--main-js.js--

```
var webnotis = require('./modules/web-notification.js')
```

--web-notification.js--

```
function getURL(host, path) {
...
}
```

Also how would I use this function in other required scripts?

---

--report-tables.js--

```
var cltvOut;
exports.cltv = function cltv(getURL)
{
  clearTimeout(cltvOut);
  cltvOut = setTimeout(function(){
    if(exports.getURL('192.168.0.15', '/IMS4/Reports/calculateCLTV'))
    {
      cltv();
    } else {
      console.log('CLTV error.')
    }
  }, 2000);
}
```

---

```
webnotis2 = require('./web-notification.js')
var cltvOut;
exports.cltv = function cltv()
{
  clearTimeout(cltvOut);
  cltvOut = setTimeout(function(){
    if(webnotis2.getUrl('192.168.0.15', '/IMS4/Reports/calculateCLTV'))
    {
      cltv();
    } else {
      console.log('CLTV error.')
    }
  }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not a part of `module.exports` then you can't. For example:

**web-notification.js**

```
function getURL(host, path) {
...
}

module.exports = exports = {
    getURL: getURL
};
```

**main-js.js**

```
var webnotis = require('./modules/web-notification.js');
webnotis.getURL(...);
```

Comment: I have tried that but when I try to access it within another module it tells me the object does not exist. Please see edit.

Comment: @imperium2335: If the function is defined and exported by *another* module, you don't access it via `exports.getURL`. `exports` only holds the values that should be exported by the *current* module. You have to access it via the variable you assigned the module to, just like freakish showed in his answer. Maybe you should have a look again at how modules work: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html.

Comment: @FelixKling I have read it and the example but it does not work when I call it from within another module.

Comment: @imperium2335: In web-notification.js, you have to do `exports.getURL = getURL;` and in main-js.js you have to do `webnotis.getURL(...)`. That's it. If that does not work, then either your module cannot be loaded because you provided the wrong path to the file or you have an error in the module, or you really did something differently. There is not much we can do besides showing how it is done.

Comment: @FelixKling But what do I have to do in report-tables.js? Which is also a module thats required in main-js.js.

Comment: @imperium2335: If you want to use the function in that module, you have to `require` it there as well.

Comment: @FelixKling I have tried that, still get the same result. Please see my edit.

Comment: If I console.log webnotis2 I get { getURL: [Function: getURL] }, so now how do I access it properly without it throwing object has no method?

Answer (score 0):

It's called exporting a module.

Sample from [here](http://visionmedia.github.io/masteringnode/book.html) :

create a file ./utils.js, and define the merge() function as seen below..

```
  function merge(obj, other) {

      //...
  };

  exports.merge = merge;
```

Now the merge function is accessible another JS in `utils` as:

```
var utils = require('./utils');

utils.merge();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var webnotis = require('./modules/web-notification.js')
      var host='urhost';
      var path='urpath'; 
      webnotis.getURL(host,path,function(err,res){
         if(!err){
               console.log('url is '+res);
            }

      });
```

web-notification.js

```
     exports.getURL=function(host, path,cb) {
            var url=host+path;
             cb(null,url);
     }
```